# Unable to establish connection to server

Tags: linux, ssh, centos, scp, nautilus

Working in CentOS. Want to have drag-and-drop SCP access to another system.

Opened up the file manager (nautilus) and went under File -> "Connect to Server". Filed in the information, hit connect. The connection will sit forever and will never properly establish. It creates an icon on my desktop, but noting else.

If I go into terminal, su to root, open nautilus and then repeat the process as a root user, then it works successfully. Connection established after I trust the remote host. File transfer works fine.

Any ideas as to what is occurring when I attempt to connect as my normal user?

Comment: What happens if you try connecting to the remote server using SSH on the command line (not as root)? If that works, what happens if you try using SCP on the command line?

Comment: Can you specify which groups your user belongs to?

Comment: @bobby, my user belongs to his group and the root users group
[bschlinker@localhost ~]$ groups bschlinker
bschlinker : bschlinker root

Comment: The does your current user have privileges to the  data you're trying to access on the server?  When you ssh to the machine, does it ask for a password, or have you established keys?

Comment: @bobby On some machines, I have established keys. On other systems, I use password based authentication. Both always work via SSH. However, when using Nautilus, I will enter my username into the field and hit connect via SSH and nothing ever happens. A mounted volume which is inaccessible appears on my desktop.

Comment: @David Sorry for my delay on response, I wasn't informed about new comments for some reason. SCP and SSH from command line work without a problem. I used SCP to sync my SSH keys to a machine a few days ago.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like a recent update to `nautilus` fixed this issue. Either that, or I've made a configuration change which fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

Try dolphin. Its a KDE app, but i know for a fact it does that and very easily. 
Simple open a tab, hit the split view, on the server tab, go to network and connect to the server and done. (personally i use fish:// to connect, but ftp ssh and a bunch of others work too)

Comment: This is a viable option if you're wiling to use a KDE app... Konqueror works as well.

Comment: I try not to change my entire environment due to a small problem though. I believe this problem is fixable, but will consider it.

Comment: Hmm Theres a few file managers...I'm not familiar with networks on most of them, but if konqueror or pacman or any others work, try it.